# Nomenclature not aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nomenclature

I have a nomenclature section in my paper where I defined my symbols.  For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-1pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\begin{document}
\begin{nomenclature}
\entry{$\hat{q}$}{Continuum scale conserved quantity}
\entry{$\hat{f}^0$}{Continuum scale source density function}
\end{nomenclature}
\end{document}
```

My code compiles properly, but the space between the symbol and its corresponding definition seems to be constant such that the definitions are not all aligned in one column.  How can I modify it to ensure that the descriptions begin at the same point?

Comment: please edit the code to be a complete document showing the problem and packages used: I guessed `nomencl.sty)` but that doesn't define `\entry`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  Done.  I don't think i used nomencl.sty unless the asme2e package implicitly uses it.  I'm not really sure.

Comment: The class file (`asme2e.cls`) isn't on CTAN as far as I can tell, could you post a link? (Is it [this one](http://code.google.com/p/me102a-sp10/source/browse/trunk/lab6/asme2e.cls?spec=svn145&r=145) for example?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Here's the link:  http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.7/asme2e.cls

Comment: @Paul The `\entry` command is defined by `\newbox\tempbox \newcommand\entry[2]{%
       \setbox\tempbox\hbox{##1.\quad}
       \hangindent\wd\tempbox\noindent{##1}\quad\ignorespaces##2\par}`. Not the best, IMO. However, if you want to submit a paper to ASME, you probably have to adhere to the style file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `asme2.cls` is the one found [here](http://code.google.com/p/me102a-sp10/source/browse/trunk/lab6/asme2e.cls?spec=svn145&r=145) it's the normal behavior. You can change it by adding the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (included) to your document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}

%%% Start of code to add
\makeatletter
\newif\if@checkentries
\renewenvironment{nomenclature}[1][]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \@checkentriesfalse
  \else
    \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1\quad}%
    \@checkentriestrue
  \fi
  \def\entry##1##2{%
    \sbox\@tempboxa{##1\quad}%
    \if@checkentries
      \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\@tempdima
        \@latex@warning{Entry `\unexpanded{##1}' is wider}%
        \@tempdima=\wd\@tempboxa
      \fi
    \else
      \@tempdima=\wd\@tempboxa
    \fi
    \hangindent\@tempdima
    \noindent\makebox[\@tempdima][l]{##1}\ignorespaces##2\par}%
    \section*{NOMENCLATURE}}
 {\par\addvspace{12pt}}
\makeatother
%% End of code to add

\begin{document}
\begin{nomenclature}[$\hat{f}^0$]
\entry{$\hat{q}$}{Continuum scale conserved quantity}
\entry{$\hat{f}^0$}{Continuum scale source density function}
\end{nomenclature}
\end{document}
```

You can specify the widest entry as an optional argument to `\begin{nomenclature}`; if you don't guess correctly, there will be a warning in the log file. For example, if you write

```
\begin{nomenclature}[$\hat{q}$]
```

you'll get the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Entry `$\hat {f}^0$' is wider on input line 31.
```

If you don't specify an optional argument, you obtain the same behavior as defined by the class.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 times.  This issue with the `asme.cls` template was bugging me _so_ much.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out the non-aligned setting is the expected behaviour of `asme2e`. Here is my take of a redefinition using a `\list`. It also indents long descriptions so that the description forms an aligned block, just like the original environment. As an optional argument my `nomenclature` environment takes the width of the symbol column, which defaults to 1cm.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}
% \addtolength{\textwidth}{-1pt}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \special{papersize=8.5in,11in}

\renewenvironment{nomenclature}[1][1cm]{%
    \newcommand\entry[2]{\item[##1]##2\par}
    \section*{NOMENCLATURE}
    \list{}{\leftmargin #1}%
  }%
  {\endlist\par\addvspace{12pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{nomenclature}
% or use \begin{nomenclature}[1.5cm] to have a wider symbol column
\entry{$\hat{q}$}{Continuum scale conserved quantity}
\entry{$\hat{f}^{0}$}{Continuum scale source density function}
\entry{$A$}{Long description long description long description long description long description long description long description long description long description}
\end{nomenclature}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]